# Jars are missing in eclipse plugin when changing computer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Always when I'm creating an eclipse plugin from jars using eclipse's wizard, everything works fine on this computer. But when I try to use the same plugin project on another computer (using git), I get dependency issues. I guess that's because the jars were not actually copied into the plugin project folder, but doing this manually doesn't help and neither I can see an option in the wizard to do so...
Btw, I've used [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html) tutorial step by step.

How can I fix dependencies without having to re-create them on each machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried, and the wizard *does* copy external JARs into the plugin project and adds them to the manifest file and `build.properties`. If you don't have the JAR(s) directly in your plugin project then something is definitely wrong; have you tried the wizard more than once, and with different JARs?

If you manually copy a JAR into the bundle project, go to the *Build* tab of the manifest editor and make sure that the JAR(s) is/are selected for inclusion under the *Binary Build* section - that's what tells Eclipse which files from the project to include when it builds/exports the bundle. Also use the *Runtime* tab to export all packages from the JAR, as described in the tutorial.

**Update:** There's an option in the wizard that you usually want to turn off: *Unzip the JAR archive into the project*. That option will dump the .class files (and other contents from the JAR(s) instead of just including the JARs themselves. As the tutorial explains, that's not usually what you want. For example, if you check the project into source control (such as cvs, svn, or git), .class files are often ignored. Best to leave the option un-checked.

Comment: I just resolved it after posting the question: Thanks to my .gitignore, *.class files were not transferred, but the wizard had just created such ones into the plugin project. But: Aren't compiled java files (i.e. *.class) platform dependent?? Anyway, it worked on my Linux/Kubuntu installation whereas the plugin/.class-files were created on win7...

Comment: `.class` files are platform independent - that's the fundamental feature of Java, that the vast majority of code written (and compiled) in it is compatible with any platform with a JVM. Even so, you usually don't want to extract the contents of a JAR for these kinds of projects.

I edited my answer to include mention of the option in the wizard that you should be aware of.

Comment: Yeah, this option was there by default, an I thought it would just refer to the jar if no enabling it... Thanks